# Aurelia validationjs

Tags: aurelia

For the life of me I can't seem to get it working.

github project [here](https://github.com/InquisitorJax/AureliaTodo)

Is this because the aurelia-validationjs project is still in flux?
Would love to get declarative validations reflecting on the UI. Tried fluent validations as well, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get aurelia validation working after following the latest post updates from http://blog.durandal.io/2016/06/14/new-validation-alpha-is-here/
I'll be updating the linked github project for anyone interested in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The aurelia-validation plugin has been rewritten recently and the validation API has changed again with respect to the accepted answer.

It is now using 2 separate libraries aurelia-validation and aurelia-validatejs. Validators do not seem to exist anymore and have been replaced by ValidationControllers.

The new API description and some examples can be found here:

http://blog.durandal.io/2016/06/14/new-validation-alpha-is-here/

.... and a working gist can be found here:

https://gist.run/?id=381fdb1a4b0865a4c25026187db865ce

The usage can be summarized in the code below:

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ValidationController, validateTrigger} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {required, email, ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validatejs';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class RegistrationForm {
  firstName = '';
  lastName = '';
  email = '';

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;      
    // the default mode is validateTrigger.blur but 
    // you can change it:
    // controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
    // controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.change;
  }

  submit() {
    let errors = this.controller.validate();
    // todo: call server...
  }

  reset() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.controller.reset();
  }
}


ValidationRules
  .ensure('firstName').required()
  .ensure('lastName').required()
.ensure('email').required().email()
.on(RegistrationForm);
```

You can also have a look at my repo in the following link:

https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AureliaAspNetCoreAuth

In the login.js I use both aurelia-validation and aurelia-validatejs....
and bootstrap-validation is made available globally in my main.js file:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
      .standardConfiguration()
      .developmentLogging()
      .plugin('aurelia-animator-css')
      .plugin('aurelia-validation')
      .plugin('aurelia-validatejs')
      .feature('bootstrap-validation'); // <= here

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

The validation renderer can be seen here:
https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AureliaAspNetCoreAuth/tree/master/src/AureliaAspNetCoreAuth/wwwroot/src/bootstrap-validation